# Do the changes made in sql reflected in core data?

Tags: iphone

I have sql as well as core data being used in my application.Now, if i make some changes suppose, update the sql db using sql queries i have those update made.If i make fetch request and print the array i see the same old value unless i quit the app and restart it.I am not able to understand this behavior.I wanted to know that if changes are made in sql db then do those changes reflect in core data table? If not, then do i have to save the updated values in coredata well and will it lead to duplicate or redundant data? 
     This is the code being used to update values:
          I have an array containing values:

```
   - (void) updateGeneraldata3 :(NSArray*) marrDataUpdate 
    {
                                                                                                   sqlite3 *database;
sqlite3_stmt *update_statement = nil;

if(sqlite3_open([strDatabasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *strMQueryupdate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE zform_general_data1 SET zChk_Mild='%@', zChk_CTV='%@', zChk_DOA='%@',           zChk_ALS1='%@' where zautonumber='%@'",[marrDataUpdate objectAtIndex:0],[marrDataUpdate objectAtIndex:1],[marrDataUpdate objectAtIndex:2],[marrDataUpdate objectAtIndex:3],autoNumberTextField.text];

    const char *sql = [strMQueryupdate UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &update_statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"update fails");
    }
    else
    {

        sqlite3_bind_text(update_statement, 1, [[marrDataUpdate objectAtIndex:0]  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(update_statement, 2, [[marrDataUpdate objectAtIndex:1]  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(update_statement, 3, [[marrDataUpdate objectAtIndex:2]  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(update_statement, 4, [[marrDataUpdate objectAtIndex:3]  UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);           
      int success = sqlite3_step(update_statement);
        sqlite3_reset(update_statement);
        if (success == SQLITE_ERROR){}
        else {}
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(update_statement);
   }
   sqlite3_close(database);   

   }
                                                                   And after update there is a background function which is executed after every 60 seconds of time .Now if i change the value of these fields on the view using the respective text fields, it updates the value in db using the above code which is also being executed after a certain interval of time  :                                                                                        


 -(void) functServerPostingData  

 {

 @try 
  {
    @autoreleasepool {


    generalDataObject = [[GeneralData alloc] init];
    generalData1_Array=[[NSArray alloc]init];
           [self checkUsedAutoNumber];
    NSError *error;
    NSManagedObjectContext *mocGeneral1 = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescriptionGeneral1 = [NSEntityDescription
                                                      entityForName:@"Form_General_Data1" inManagedObjectContext:mocGeneral1];
    NSFetchRequest *requestGeneral1;

    requestGeneral1 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    [requestGeneral1 setEntity:entityDescriptionGeneral1];

    generalData1_Array=[mocGeneral1 executeFetchRequest:requestGeneral1 error:&error];
     NSLog(@"generalData1_Array :%@",generalData1_Array);
                if(!generalData1_Array)
    {

        NSLog(@"Error fetching Login: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        abort();

    }


    for(int i = 0; i< [generalData1_Array count]; i++)  {
        for (int j=0;j<[[strAutoNumber componentsSeparatedByString:@","] count] ; j++)
        {

            if([[[generalData1_Array objectAtIndex:i] Autonumber ] isEqualToString: [[strAutoNumber componentsSeparatedByString:@","]objectAtIndex:j]])
            {
                generalDataObject.AutoNumber=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[generalData1_Array objectAtIndex:i] Autonumber ]]; 

                generalDataObject.Chk_Mild =[[generalData1_Array objectAtIndex:i]Chk_Mild];

                generalDataObject.Chk_CTV=[[generalData1_Array objectAtIndex:i]Chk_CTV];


                generalDataObject.Chk_PAU=[[generalData1_Array objectAtIndex:i]Chk_PAU];
                                   generalDataObject.Transient=[[generalData1_Array objectAtIndex:i]Transient];

              generalDataObject.Chk_ALS1=  [[generalData1_Array objectAtIndex:i]Chk_ALS1];


              [generalDataObject startPostServerData];
            }
        }
    }

    if (generalDataObject.checkRequest==TRUE) 
    {
        [appDelegate CheckInternetConnection];
        if(appDelegate.internetWorking==-1)
        {
        }
        else {
            serverLinkToHit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/ReceiveData.aspx?m=InsertData&t=GeneralData",[serverLinkSettings getServerLink ]];
            [generalDataObject readServerData:serverLinkToHit postServerData:generalDataObject.finalDataString];
        }

    }
    generalDataObject = nil;
        requestGeneral1=nil;
        requestGeneral2=nil;
    }
    } 
@catch (NSException *exception)
  {
    [ExceptionLog LogEntry:exception :@"Error while entering data functServerPostingData"];
 }


 }
```

I have printed the array which always shows the previous old value irrespective of what i have entered in text field and saving in db.However, at the same place i print the values of sql db they are updated.Shall i use sql select to select value put it in an array and then post?

Comment: Are you accessing CoreData's SQLite backing store directly?

Comment: @Eimantas Yes i am using sql.

Comment: Don't do that. It's a very bad practice. CoreData is object graph, not a database.

Comment: @Eimantas So, what should be the correct approach?If you could explain.Actually , i am posting some values.If i post by extracting from sql db then it get posted with the latest value otherwise using fetch query doesn't do that.

Comment: Post some code that does the update.

Comment: This isn't a good idea. You'll probably get away with this for awhile, but it'll catch up to you - either something in the framework implementation will change and break all your code, or it will just get really difficult to maintain, or you'll need to migrate your Core Data store to a new persistent store type. Just use SQL if you need SQL, or fix your Core Data bugs if you're doing this as a workaround.

Comment: @Carl Veazey : So according to you , i should use sql to get all the values and post them.I should't use core data for this?

Comment: @user1693436 No, sorry. What I mean is that you shouldn't mix them up. If you are having a problem with Core Data, that you are trying to fix by doing something in SQL, then you need to fix the actual bug and not rely on this workaround. On the other hand, if you were doing some sophisticated data work requiring a relational database then you shouldn't be using Core Data for that. Does that make sense? Basically I say, fix your Core Data bug preventing you from posting "the latest value otherwise using fetch query doesn't do that". Don't fall back to SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

No. That's not how Core Data works. The format of the database is not documented and you're not supposed to play around with it.

I think the real question here is: why do you think you need to use SQL? Looks like you're just updating a few records. This is pretty straight-forward using "native" Core Data.

Comment: I was thinking of using sql because the core data does not shows me the latest value however the sql does.So as mentioned in previous comments, this wouldn't be the right approach to do so.Probably i have to look why core data is not updating my values .

Comment: Core Data doesn't automatically synchronise data _between managed object contexts_. But you can listen for update events and merge them in.

Comment: Ok i will insert values in core data separately.